# getting N values from getline(cin) for different data types

Tags: c++

I have created a program, which requires user to define at least 2 arguments(3rd is optional). Arguments are:

1. Command(string type)
2. Date(custom type/class)
3. Event(string type) - Optional.

I have come up with the following idea:

```
int main() {
    Database db /*my custom class */
    string command;
    vector<string> arguments;
    while (getline(cin, command, ' ')) {
        arguments.push_back(command);
    }
```

and after that the idea was to use indexing for arguments:

```
if(arguments[0] == "Add"){
        Date date arguments[1];
        db.Add(date,arguments[2])
}

} else if(arguments[0] == "Find"){
        Date date = arguments[1];
        db.Find(date);
```

But unfortunately,  `Date date = arguments[1];` doesn't work. How can I handle a problem of user input arguments with different data types, with one argument optional.

Here is my Date class:

```
class Date {
public:
    Date(){
        

    };
    Date(int new_year, int new_month, int new_day){
        if(new_month > 12 || new_month < 1){
            throw invalid_argument("Month value is invalid: " + to_string(new_month));
        } else if (new_day > 31 || new_day < 1){
            throw invalid_argument("Day value is invalid: " + to_string(new_day));
        }
        year = new_year;
        month = new_month;
        day = new_day;

    }
    int GetYear() const{
        return year;
    };
    int GetMonth() const{
        return month;
    };
    int GetDay() const{
        return day;
    };
private:
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};


bool operator<(const Date& lhs, const Date& rhs){
    if(lhs.GetYear() != rhs.GetYear()){
        return (lhs.GetYear() - rhs.GetYear()) < 0;
    } else if(lhs.GetMonth() != rhs.GetMonth()){
        return (lhs.GetMonth() - rhs.GetMonth()) < 0;
    } else {
        return (lhs.GetDay() - rhs.GetDay()) < 0;
    }
};


bool operator>(const Date& lhs, const Date& rhs){
    if(lhs.GetYear() != rhs.GetYear()){
        return (lhs.GetYear() - rhs.GetYear()) > 0;
    } else if(lhs.GetMonth() != rhs.GetMonth()){
        return (lhs.GetMonth() - rhs.GetMonth()) > 0;
    } else {
        return (lhs.GetDay() - rhs.GetDay()) > 0;
    }
};


bool operator==(const Date& lhs, const Date& rhs){
    if(lhs.GetYear() == rhs.GetYear() && lhs.GetMonth() == rhs.GetMonth() && lhs.GetDay() == rhs.GetDay()){
        return true;
        }
    return false;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const Date& date){
    stream << date.GetYear() << '-' << date.GetMonth() << '-' << date.GetDay();
    return stream;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& stream, Date& d) { //возвращать будем ссылку на поток
    //if (stream) return stream;
    int year,month,day;
    char c;

    stream >> year >> c >> month >> c >> day;

    if (stream && c == '-')
        d = Date(year,month,day);

    return (stream);
}
```

Comment: what is this line supposed to do? `Date date arguments[1];` ? Do you mean `Date date{arguments[1]};` ? Probably no, because there is no constructor of `Date` that takes 1 parameter

Comment: Date date = <whatever> calls a constructor ( like Date date(<whatever>);  ). I do not see constructor for date from one string

Comment: It's just missing an `=`.  I'm confident it's intended to look like the one below it.  `Date date = arguments[1]`.

Comment: Answering this question currently requires too much guesswork. Construct a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But unfortunately, `Date date = arguments[1];` doesn't work.

Correct, because `arguments[1]` is a `std::string`, but `Date` does not have a constructor that accepts a `std::string`.  So add one, eg:

```
class Date {
public:
    Date() {
        setDate(0, 1, 1);
    };

    Date(int new_year, int new_month, int new_day) {
        setDate(new_year, new_month, new_day);
    }

    Date(const string &str) {
        int new_year, new_month, new_day;
        // parse str to extract new_year, new_month, new_day as needed...
        setDate(new_year, new_month, new_day);
    }

    void setDate(int new_year, int new_month, int new_day) {
        if(new_month > 12 || new_month < 1){
            throw invalid_argument("Month value is invalid: " + to_string(new_month));
        } else if (new_day > 31 || new_day < 1){
            throw invalid_argument("Day value is invalid: " + to_string(new_day));
        }
        year = new_year;
        month = new_month;
        day = new_day;
    }
    ...
};
```

There are many ways to parse a string to extract sub values.  For instance, you can use:

- `string::find()` + `string::substr()` + `std::stoi()`
- `std::istringstream` + `operator>>`
- `std::sscanf()`
- `std::regex`
- etc

Use whatever you are most comfortable with.  Just for demonstration purposes, let's use `std::sscanf()`:

```
#include <cstdio>

class Date {
public:
    ...

    Date(const string &str) {
        int new_year, new_month, new_day;
        if ((sscanf(str.c_str(), "%4d-%2d-%2d", &new_year, &new_month, &new_day) != 3) &&
            (sscanf(str.c_str(), "%4d/%2d/%2d", &new_year, &new_month, &new_day) != 3)) {
           throw invalid_argument("Str value is invalid: " + str);
        }
        setDate(new_year, new_month, new_day);
    }

    ...
};
```

---

On a side note, you might consider using command-line arguments instead of input I/O, eg:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    ...
    vector<string> arguments;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        arguments.push_back(argv[i]);
    }
    ...
}
```

And then users can call your program like this:

```
program.exe command date event
```

Instead of running `program.exe` first and then entering `command`, `date`, and `event` separately.

Answer (score -3):

`Date date = <whatever>`
calls a constructor (like `Date date(<whatever>);` ). I do not see a constructor for `Date` that takes a string.

This notation is only available for constructors that have one argument.
Generally `=` is an assignment operator call, or sometimes a constructor call (namely, when you declare a variable like in `Date date = ...;` as opposed to `Date date; date = ...;` – this would be an assignment operator call).

You can write `Date date(int1, int2, int3);` where the `int`s are obviously some `int`s retrieved from the input. You have to either give it 3 `int`s (as you have in the constructor) – or else, to make the `main()` code simpler, write a constructor taking a string and retrieve `int`s from the string.

Comment: _"How can I handle a problem of user input arguments with different data types, with one argument optional."_ was the question.  How does this answer that?

Comment: well, he can transform strings that he gets into the types that he needs. that's the bottom line, and as a new C++ user OP might be in the dark with basic matters that I try to clear out. I'm curious if my answer will help still, I gotta admit